Error: Systemctl Failed to enable unit: Cannot alias service
This was previously working just fine, but a failed micro-sd card on a Raspberry Pi Zero W forced me to reinstall the system.  The old system was running on an older release of the OS, so that could definitely be part of the issue.  When I issue the command:
systemctl enable i2cget.service

I get the error:
Failed to enable unit: Cannot alias i2cget.service as i2cget

and no symlink is created.
Oddly enough, when I check the status, it says it is enabled, and when I reboot, the service is live.  I don't understand what is going on.  Could there be an issue with the fact the symlink does not exist in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants?
This us running under Raspbian 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3
/lib/systemd/system/i2cget.service:
[Unit]
Description=get-i2c daemon
After=network.target
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=4s
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/fpp/media/scripts/get-i2c.py

[Install]
Alias=i2cget
WantedBy=multi-user.target


From man systemd.unit:

Aliases obey the following restrictions: a unit of a certain type (".service", ".socket", ...) can only be aliased by a name with the same type suffix.

You have to remove the line with Alias or change it to Alias=something-different-than-i2cget.service
